# My package is using react-native-svg, package is listed in node_modules after npm i but getting err

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-svg

I have developed an npm package for React Native (myPackage).

As might you know React Native doesn't have built-in support to handle SVG images so I am using this package `react-native-svg` for handling SVGs in my `myPackage`

After developing I have created a new React Native app (create-react-native-app my-project) and installed myPackage through `npm I myPackage`

so, the problem is when I install `myPackage` in `my-project` it installed successfully and listed in `node_modules` but I am getting an error that the `RNSVGPath was not found` but it actually exists in `node_modules`

Workaround:
It works if I install the package again in `my-project`

It shouldn't be like this because my-project must use dependencies of `myPackage`. I don't want to install manually `react-native-svg`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `react-native-cli` or the expo bare workflow, it's probably because you didn't run `pod install` after installation

Comment: Facing it on android. Yeah, i am using React Native CLI